# complex routing with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Looking for best practice of Symfony (4) routing action for my URL schema. 
Let's say I'm detecting GEO IP and showing different language for web users even in URL.
So what best practice would be to develop routing?

link examples,
when a user comes from the USA:

```
example.com/static_link_in_en/additional_static_element_in_en/special_static_element_in_en/extra_static_attribute_in_en
example.com/product_name_in_en/additional_element_of_product_in_en/special_element_for_this_item_in_en/extra_attribute_in_en
```

when a user comes from France:

```
example.com/static_link_in_fr/additional_static_element_in_fr/special_static_element_in_fr/extra_static_attribute_in_fr
example.com/product_name_in_fr/additional_element_of_product_in_fr/special_element_for_this_item_in_fr/extra_attribute_in_fr
```

another, maybe better example:

```
example.com/tag - static route, generates a tag cloud in EN
example/tag/ - static route, but displays an error or 404 page, because we are not searching in the database with an empty string in EN
example.com/tag/red - searching in the database with keyword 'red'
example.com/tag/blue - exceptional keyword, we have reserved tag 'blue' so the script will not be searching in the database, the static route will be used in EN
```

the same actions just translated in the French language:

```
example.com/marque 

example.com/marque/

example.com/marque/rouge
```

let's say URL deep level can be up to 10 elements, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better policy is to include the locale in the URL. This is fully-supported by the routing system using the special _locale parameter.

```
# config/routes.yaml
contact:
    path:       /{_locale}/contact
    controller: App\Controller\ContactController::index
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr|de
```

When using the special _locale parameter in a route, the matched locale is automatically set on the Request and can be retrieved via the getLocale() method. In other words, if a user visits the URI /fr/contact, the locale fr will automatically be set as the locale for the current request.

You can now use the locale to create routes to other translated pages in your application.

Source : https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html

Symfony doesn't support defining routes with different contents depending on the user language. In those cases, you can define multiple routes per controller, one for each supported language; or use any of the bundles created by the community to implement this feature, such as JMSI18nRoutingBundle and BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle.

Source : https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#translating-routes